# How to include guidelines from an organisation in your research paper?

Tags: writing-style

I am including several guidelines from different organizations such as WHO in my research paper. The guidelines will be copied and pasted into my paper under the heading of their organisation. For example:

> WHO guidline:
>
> [Guideline Text]

Will this be considered plagiarism? Do I have to include the whole text in quotation marks or is the title "WHO guideline" adequate to show it is not my work. The other option is to just put down a link rather than copy and paste the guidelines but I need them to be in the paper for compare and contrast purposes.

Comment: How long is the guideline? I have a hard time imagining WHO guideline is less than 2 pages.

Comment: They are actually very short, the longest one is only 5 parapraghs long. All of the guidlines fit in a page and a half.

Comment: It isn't plagiarism if it is cited. But it still might not be proper. Plagiarism is not what you think it is.

Comment: 5 paragraphs is a very very unusually long length of quote for any paper I've seen.

Comment: Why would you include a page of copied guidelines? If you want to discuss something relevant within these guidelines, cite that part. Otherwise refer to them by a link/reference

Answer (score 1):

Of course it depends on the context how to use citations in the text. A very important aspect in scientifc literature (especially scientific article papers) is to be as precise and compressed as possible. Therefore my approach with guidelines would be to choose those paragraphs that are important for my work and to include only those with (WHO, 20xx(a,b,c...), p.xx) at the end of the sentence.

The fact that these are WHO guidelines is obvious I don't think you need "WHO guidelines": as introduction words.

If you take complete sentences word for word I would put them in quotation marks and put (WHO, 20xx(a,b,c...), p.xx) at the end of the sentence.